# OCaml: Unbound module error when compiling multiple files

Tags: ocaml

So I am writing a multiple-file program in OCaml and my directory structure looks like this:

```
src
 |- module1.ml
 |- section1
     |- module2.ml
     |- module3.ml
```

Where module1 opens module2 and module3, and module2 opens module3.

I compile the program with the following:

```
ocamlopt -o bin/myprog src/module1.ml src/section1/module2.ml src/section1/module3.ml
```

It throws in error in module2.ml saying that Module3 is unbound.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the order in which **.cmx** and **.ml** arguments are presented on the command line is relevant. This means that **module1** which appears to be using both **module2** and **module3** should be in last position and not first as you're doing here.

You will also need to add the `-I directory` option to add the given directory to the list of directories searched for.

This should do the job:

```
ocamlopt -o bin/myprog -I src/section1 src/section1/module3.ml src/section1/module2.ml src/module1.ml
```

Comment: Oops. I meant module2 says that module3 is unbound. My bad.

Comment: ok than it should be sufficient to put the module in the right order when calling ocamlopt, isn't it?

Comment: Apparently not. Maybe it'll work if I compile them to bytecode first, then use `ocamlopt` and compile _them_ into native code?

Comment: Ok so you need to add the `-I dir` option to have it work as i show in my edited answer. I've also removed the cyclic dependancy thing as it is not useful anymore.